# Intercept every single Request of react native webview

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webview, interceptor

I'm trying to create a WebView which has a hook that catches on every single request, intercepts it, allows me to **edit** it and send it afterwards. But I am not able to find a way to intercept every request of the webview (not only just a url change using onNavigationStateChange).

The next step would be to change the response as well.

Any ideas how it would be possible to achieve something like this in React Native?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: As mentioned above I've tried to use onNavigationStateChange. But it doesn’t catch on every request. So I’ve tried to make my calls by myself and only render the finished result which I wasn’t be able to do. I got the correct html but I wasn’t able to load the complete homepage with css and JavaScript which makes a website unusable. But it could be a way to go where I just can’t get any further.

Answer (score 2):

You can try injecting js to intercept the HTTP request/response with the help of XMLHttpRequest. This is what I had done for my purpose;

```
const MyWebview = props => {

const INJECTED_JAVASCRIPT = `(function() {
var open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
    this.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var message = {"status" : this.status, "response" : this.response}
        window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify(message));
    });
    open.apply(this, arguments);
};})();`;

return (
  <WebView
    source={{ uri: 'https://example.com/' }}
    injectedJavaScript={INJECTED_JAVASCRIPT}
    onMessage={event => {
      console.log('>>>', event);
    }}
  />
 );
};

export default NewsWebview;
```

Basically what we are doing here is, adding a listener here, on `INJECTED_JAVASCRIPT`, to track every successful XMLHttpRequest transaction completion. And using

```
window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify(message));
```

we are sending every response to WebView via `onMessage` prop.
[More on how XMLHttpRequest works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: I actually tried something similar to this. The issue with this solution is that it covers only a small fraction of all requests. All fetch requests can be caught using the same approach, but for images, videos, favicon retrievals, cross origin preflight requests, etc. you're pretty much out of luck.

Comment: I haven't tried those things yet. Thanks for the insight. I had used this approach to get a CSV file from a response (blob type) and it's working fine.